# Handle Entity Framework OptimisticConcurrencyException

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Evaluating the .NET Entity Framework I try to find the right patterns to handle concurrent updates with optimistic concurrency mode.

In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx) and many other places I see the following pattern:

```
Try
  ' Try to save changes, which may cause a conflict. 
  Dim num As Integer = context.SaveChanges()
  Console.WriteLine("No conflicts. " & num.ToString() & " updates saved.")
Catch generatedExceptionName As OptimisticConcurrencyException
  ' Resolve the concurrency conflict by refreshing the 
  ' object context before re-saving changes. 
  context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, orders)

  ' Save changes. 
  context.SaveChanges()
  Console.WriteLine("OptimisticConcurrencyException handled and changes saved")
End Try
```

I see the following problems with this

- it automatically implements last-in-wins instead of using optimistic mode
- it is not robust: concurrent changes between .Refresh and .SaveChanges can cause a new OptimisticConcurrencyException

**Is this correct, or am I missing something?**

In a UI I normally let the user resolve the concurrency conflict:

```
Try
   _ctx.SaveChanges()
Catch ex As OptimisticConcurrencyException
   MessageBox.Show("Data was modified by another User." & vbCrLf &
   "Click 'Refresh' to show the current values and reapply your changes.",
   "Concurrency Violation", MessageBoxButton.OK)
End Try
```

In business logic I normally use a retry loop around the whole business transaction (reading and updating):

```
Const maxRetries = 5, retryDelayMs = 500
For i = 1 To maxRetries
    Try
        Using ctx As New EFConcurrencyTest.ConcurrencyTestEntities
            ctx.Inventories.First.QuantityInStock += 1
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) 'Cause conflict
            ctx.SaveChanges()
        End Using
        Exit For
    Catch ex As OptimisticConcurrencyException
        If i = maxRetries Then Throw
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(retryDelayMs)
    End Try
Next
```

With EF I plan to encapsulate the loop:

```
ExecuteOptimisticSubmitChanges(Of EFConcurrencyTest.ConcurrencyTestEntities)(
    Sub(ctx)
        ctx.Inventories.First.QuantityInStock += 1
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) 'Cause conflict
    End Sub)
```

See:

[Functional Optimistic Concurrency in C#](http://www.jdconley.com/blog/archive/2009/06/26/functional-optimistic-concurrency-in-c.aspx)

[Retryable actions in C#](http://philbolduc.blogspot.com/2010/03/retryable-actions-in-c.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
Catch ex As OptimisticConcurrencyException
  ' Resolve the concurrency conflict by refreshing the 
  ' object context before re-saving changes. 
  context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, orders)

  ' Save changes. 
  context.SaveChanges()
  Console.WriteLine("OptimisticConcurrencyException handled and changes saved")
```

...is completely pointless. If the only thing you do when you "handle" the exception is to ignore it and save anyway, you should just turn optimistic concurrency off; you're writing code to work around an optional feature.

So, yes, I'd say the documentation is not giving you good advice here.

Your proposed UI code is a better solution.